# Cant figure Xorg Configure on Nvidia optimus and Bios Legacy on FreeBSD

Tags: xorg, freebsd, system-installation, graphic-card

I have a difficult thing to set up Xorg on my laptop nvidia optimus,

- Allienware M11x R3
- Intel i7-4xxx
- Nvidia gt 540M and intel driver
- Ram 8 GB

When i install Xorg on Freebsd and `startx`, it failed.

I tried to create specific driver to enable just one driver because my laptop cant run both driver on Freebsd. I tried all driver Vesa, Sfcb, and Intel and Nvidia on `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/driver-vesa.conf`, or `intel-driver.conf` or `nvidia-driver.conf`. But it cant load and get same error.

I tried to figure out to run `X -configure` and tried `startx`, again it is still same.

When i tun TrueOS it works when i run `X -configure` then `startx`

[image]

And the error outputs on freebsd when I run `startx` without `X -configure` are [here](https://pastebin.com/P8APnSn5)